# include multiple functions in Python class and object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to the concept of "class" and "objects" in Python, I succeeded in defining a single function using:

```
# build the object "test"
class test:
    def __init__(self,raw_data):
        self.method1 = raw_data*10
        self.method2 = raw_data*20
        self.method3 = raw_data*30
        
# a quick test using "raw_data = 1"
output = test(1)

# here three methods are all working
print(output.method1)
print(output.method2)
print(output.method3) 

# outputs
10
20
30
```

But in real work, how can I include a lot of functions/processing steps under this "class" or "object" thing. So I can run all of them together. The codes below failed (only the first function was working):

```
# build the object "test"
class test:
    def __init__(self,raw_data):
        self.method1 = raw_data*10
    
    def compute_method_2(self,raw_data):    
        self.method2 = raw_data*20
        
    def compute_method_3(self,raw_data):    
        self.method3 = raw_data*30
        
# a quick test using "raw_data = 1"
output = test(1)

# now only the first calculation worked
print(output.method1)
print(output.method2) 
print(output.method3)

# Error report:
AttributeError: 'test' object has no attribute 'method2'
```

Many thanks for your help!

To clarify why I want to split the functions: This is just a simplified example. In real work, there are multiple functions needed for different processing steps, and those functions work on different items.

Comment: You will need to *call* `compute_method_2` at some point, which you're not doing. Only `__init__` is called on instantiation, anything else you need to call as and when needed to interact with your object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, Python methods only run if you choose to run them. You've gotten tripped up because your first encounter with methods is `__init__()`, but that is actually a weird exception to that rule: it's run immediately when you create each object of that class (that's the whole point of `__init__()`). So you need to run those methods manually if you want them to run:

```
# a quick test using "raw_data = 1"
output = test(1)

# run other computations
output.compute_method_2(1)
output.compute_method_3(1)

# now all the values are available
print(output.method1)
print(output.method2) 
print(output.method3)
```

If you want the methods to run when you create the objects, which it looks like you do here, it's better put that code in `__init__()` rather than manually calling them every time you make an object - remember, that's why `__init__()` is there! But maybe your `__init__()` was getting too big and that's why you wanted to split it up. In that case, you can put your code into methods still, but call them from `__init__()` (and then you *don't* need to call them separately like the above example):

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,raw_data):
        self.method1 = raw_data*10
        self.compute_method_2(raw_data)
        self.compute_method_3(raw_data)
    
    def compute_method_2(self,raw_data):    
        self.method2 = raw_data*20
        
    def compute_method_3(self,raw_data):    
        self.method3 = raw_data*30
```

By the way, a "method" is a member function of a class, like your `compute_method_2()` function (and like `__init__()`!). *Data* members are not methods, so it is confusing that you used names like `self.method2` for these.